# BATCH : Change special characters from filenames (é è à...)

Tags: csv, batch-file, terminal, special-characters, dos

I'm trying to replace special characters from a string in batch. I've tried this :

```
set filename=%filename:é=e%
set filename=%filename:è=e%
```

But it doesn't work!

DOS doesn't understand any of these characters properly for some reason. Here's a screenshot
(Note that the OUTPUT IN CSV is NOT part of the code. I just posted what was echo'd into the .csv just for you to see).

(Not Enough Reputation to post screenshots...)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSqBk.png)

So yeah, i have different characters in the program, in the terminal and also in the output file. Now i don't know what to do with special characters with accents. Optimal would be a single line of code that deletes them all from the string, no need to replace.

Something like :

```
 set filename=%filename:À à Ä ä Â â É é È è Ë ë Ê ê Ì ì Ï ï Î î Ò ò Ö ö Ô ô Ù ù Ü ü Û û=%
```

That would simply kill them all, and i would input this line before shooting the output into the .csv file. Would solve the problem but i can't get my hands on that function in BATCH (I've seen solutions in .NET or other languages but none in BATCH)

Comment: Your batch file is saved in UTF8... Command prompt has problems with UTF8 batch files. You could try with a Powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch can properly manage any Ascii character, that is, characters with code below or equal 255. This is obvious, because the Batch code itself must also be written in Ascii.

```
@echo off
set remove=áéíóúÜü
set string=Aaá Eeé Iií Ooó UuÜüú It Works!
for /F "tokens=1-26 delims=%remove%" %%a in ("%string%") do (
   set newString=%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j%%k%%l%%m%%n%%o%%p%%q%%r%%s%%t%%u%%v%%w%%x%%y%%z
)
echo "%newString%"
```

Output:

```
"Aa Ee Ii Oo Uu It Works!"
```

If the characters you want to remove are *not* Ascii (codes above 255), then a Batch program can not solve this problem.

Comment: First; Works like a charm Thanks. Second, i was only wondering if the tokens could go higher than 26. Cause yeah, when we get files from remote countries there's really tons of special characters we need to trim... :x

Comment: @Quardah batch is not a good solution for those. Use a better scripting language like python, perl, ruby... or if not possible use VBS or JS

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your Batch File.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

@CHCP 65001 >NUL
```

And this working

```
set filename=%filename:é=e%

set filename=%filename:è=e%
```